# Iterating through rows and filtering data in R

Tags: r, classification

I am working with the following data (see picture)

I am trying to predict future Y axis values from the X values. As you can tell from the picture and as I discovered, the prediction is going to be horrible based on the data alone.

I am now trying to go row by row through the data and classify each point as significant or nonsignificant and see if I can find anything interesting in the classification. I want my algorithm something like this:

1. Take absolute value of every element in both Y axis and X axis data columns
2. Iterate through Y axis column and find the top 5% largest values
3. Iterate through again marking those top 5% or maybe 1% (Will fiddle with this) with a flag
4. Plot only the top 5% and see if the linear model (or some model) has a better R^2
5. Perform some sort of classification analysis against the two flags, significant and non significant (I really need help and suggestions with this step)

   [image]

The two things I need are a pointer on are

- How to step element by element through data, making modifications along the way
- What kind of classification analysis exists that might be helpful, goal being to predict which classification future sampled elements will fall into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't step element by element through data in R. Well, you can, but you need to be a very patient person.

The R way would be to calculate the quantile you want and subset the data.

Example:

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x=runif(1e3),y=rlnorm(1e3))
plot(y~x,data=DF)

#95 % quantile
q95 <- quantile(DF$y,0.95)

#plot data subset
plot(y~x,data=DF[DF$y>q95,])

#fit linear model to data subset
fit <- lm(y~x,data=DF[DF$y>q95,])
abline(fit)
```

Can't help you with the statistical issue ...

Comment: Hey this helped a lot. I really needed some help with the basic subset commands.